# Selenium don't run ExecuteScript change option

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, selenium

Hello i am trying to make onChange event on select list,i found javascript that works `$('#ddlAcounts').val("123").trigger('change')`

i test it in firebug in console , all works fine event work,but when i run it in selenium(Phantom) it doesn't work,i didn't get any error ,but page are not changing.

What i am missing here?

Here how i run my script

`$('#ddlAcounts').val("123").trigger('change')`

that do work in webBrowser console.

My code

```
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = browserToRun as IJavaScriptExecutor;
  js.ExecuteScript("$('#ddlAcounts').val("123").trigger('change')");
```

Comment: Did you try running it with ... val('123') instead of val("123") ?

Comment: Yes this was a problem all works now.thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll copy the answer from the comments, so that the question is marked as answered. The following is the solution, see the changed (") marks at val

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = browserToRun as IJavaScriptExecutor;
 js.ExecuteScript("$('#ddlAcounts').val('123').trigger('change')");
```